# Torsion points of elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

I'm studying "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" by Silverman and I'm having trouble with the torsion subgroup.

Corollary 6.4 at page 86 states that the subgroup $E[m]$ which is the $m$-torsion subgroup is isomorphic as a group to $Z/mZ \times Z/mZ$ if $m$ is coprime to the characteristic of the field.

While it's not clear, it seems logical that he is talking about an algebraically closed field.

What bugs me is that at page 175, proposition 5.4 he proves the same proposition for complex elliptic curves (using the corrispondence with lattices) without any acknowledgement of the existence of the previous proof which should be more general.

Is there a reason for this? Or is just a little oversight on the part of Silverman?

Comment: Isn't it good to have two different ways of seeing the same result?

Comment: Yes, but I'm used to read something along the line of "here it's another proof of an already known fact" in similar cases, so I was afraid I missed something

Comment: I forgot that hypotesist, added for clarity

Comment: See p.90 and II.2.6b, the idea is to write $\# ker(\phi)$ as the degree $deg(\phi)$ of the **separable** field extension $\overline{K}(E)/\overline{K}(\phi(E))$, and to show that with $\phi = [m]$ then $deg (\phi) = m^2$  (if $m$ is not coprime with $char(K)$ then the extension is not necessary separable)

Comment: That being said, it seems in the case $K = \mathbb{C}$, the Weierstrass function and the complex torus is a completely different argument. @LordSharktheUnknown